# Selecting multiple DataTable Row by Ctrl + Click

Tags: jquery, datatables

There is an example on the DataTables Website [here](http://www.datatables.net/release-datatables/extras/TableTools/select_multi.html) which shows multiple selection being implemented on single clicks.

The usability of this feature is quite less, as multiple selection is better presented by holding down <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and clicking the row.

The source code is too confusing to study thoroughly. Have anyone done this before and point me to the right way?

Answer (score 1):

Just add a click event to the TR's and toggle a "selected" class (could be any class name or attribute you want. The key aspects are using event.ctrlKey to check if the control key is down and using jqueries .siblings() and .removeClass() functions.

```
$("#demo tbody").delegate("tr", "click", function(event){
    var $row = $(event.target);
    if($row[0].tagName !== "TR") $row = $row.parent();
    $row.toggleClass("selected");
    if(event.ctrlKey === false) {
        $row.siblings().removeClass("selected");
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/9FMBv/